# Class 'Predis\Client' not found in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, redis, dependencies, composer-php

I installed redis by

```
composer require  predis/predis
```

then I changed my config/queue.php like this:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis'),
```

however when I try to use redis:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
Redis::connection();
```

I get this error :

> FatalErrorException in Database.php line 63: Class 'Predis\Client' not
>   found

Edit:

Actually I installed Redis on local host and I uploaded only 'vendor' folder to server. Can it be because of, while installation is there any other file created except from in "vendor" folder?

What can be the problem? I use laravel 5.0
thanks,,

Comment: What is the output of the command `composer info | grep predis`?

Comment: Try `composer require predis/predis`

Comment: @DavidSmith I get empty response for `composer info | grep predis`. However, for `composer info | grep redis` I get `doctrine/cache 2.1.1 PHP Doctrine Cache library is a popular cache implementation ...`

Answer (score 1):

After setting your `.env` file for redis try running `php artisan config:cache`.